Unable to connect to Oracle db via thick mode through dbt
I am unable to connect to oracle database using dbt.
It keeps using thin mode and throws DPY-3015 error however I want it to use thick mode. I am using windows machine.
I have OCI libraries installed and environmental variable in place for instanclient path.
I tried adding new line in profiles.yml
“Method: thick”
It didn’t work. Please help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Review the python-oracledb troubleshooting doc on DPY-3015 in case you can quickly resolve the issue and use Thin mode.
If you still need to use Thick mode then set ORA_PYTHON_DRIVER_TYPE=thick as instructed in the Configuring dbt-oracle doc.
